# How to SSH into windows PC/Linux from Alpine Linux on IOS (iSH)

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, ios, alpine-linux

I am using the iSH app on iOS for my iPhone.

I've set it up and everything seems to work correctly. I'm root and set my own password, did apk add openssh-server. However when I try to SSH into my Windows PC with mypcname@ipv4address, it just says SSH command not found.

Anyone know why this is? I've never really used Alpine Linux.

Comment: Have you installed and configured OpenSSH Server?

Comment: i have ssh setup on my pc correctly (windows) with openssh. How do i do this on iSH ? can you give me a quick guide

Comment: What step are you stuck on?

Comment: idk what the steps are, the issue iam facing is the one in my question

Comment: [iSH](https://github.com/ish-app/ish/) based on my research just provides a shell.  It does not actually over SSH capabilities.  What that tells me is you would have to install the OpenSSH client.  iSH appears to be iOS equipment of Cygwin

Comment: I googled `ish shell install ssh`. Here's just one of the results: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pImoGaKX7y4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pImoGaKX7y)

Comment: @Mj_ - Have you installed SSH within iSh? In other words have you ran `apk add openssh`?  This is the reason I asked you what step you are stuck on.  You should [edit] your question to better reflect what you have done